# Changing viewcontrollers with smooth push transition and without navigationcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, ios6, presentviewcontroller

I'm trying to change from `viewcontroller` view1 to `viewcontroller` view2 with a smooth and nice transition, where view1 gets pushed to the left by view2 within a second. I have made a simple illustration of what I want in my iPhone app.

[image] --> [image] --> [image] --> [image]

I am using storyboard and developing for iOS 6 and higher. I'm not using segues. Currently I'm using this code to change from view1 to view2 without any animations in Xcode:

```
SecondViewController *viewTwo = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"View2"];
[self presentViewController:viewTwo animated:NO completion:nil];
```

I am looking for code that can replace my existing code with. Code that changes from view1 to view2 with the push transition

**NOTE**: I am not using `NavigationControllers`! Just normal `ViewControllers`. I would prefer to do this with codes.

**EDIT**: I understand that this would be very easy to do if I used a navigation controller, but the problem is that I'm done building the storyboard and I have already buildt everything using normal view controller. And that creates my second question:

Are there any way I can simply convert my `UIViewControllers` to work as `UINavigationControllers`. Without having to delete my `UIViewController` and build it again only using `UINavController`?

**ANSWER**: I solved my problem by implementing a navigation controller to my project. I have totally misunderstood the whole concept of navigations controllers earlier, but I have now figured it out. So my problem is solved!

Comment: Why do you not want to use a navigation controller? If you hide the navigation bar, you'll get exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: I would very much prefer a non nav controller to do this, since I am almost done with my app, and I dont want to start building the storyboard all over again, since it will be one hell of a job. Whats why I would very much prefer an answer not using nav controller.

Comment: Do your controllers need to handle rotations? If so, you either need to use the custom container controller api, or some pretty complex code to get this to work correctly.

Comment: What do you mean by rotations? If you mean rotating the the view from a vertical position, then no, I don't mean by rotation.

Comment: you known that it is possible to hide the navigationcontroller?

Comment: @rdelmar Please read my EDIT in the question, and give me some feedback if that could be a possible solution.

Comment: You don't need to delete anything to use navigation controllers. Just embed the first controller in a navigation controller, and change all your segues to pushes. It might be a little more complicated than that, but I can't tell without knowing the structure of your app.

Comment: Clearly I have misunderstood the whole concept of using navigation controllers. I have implemented a navigation controller to my project and I figured out how to use it to get the transitions i wanted between my view controllers. Thanks for replying! It helped me a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set animation for the view2. Use this code.

```
-(void)ViewNavigationOnLeftTabs
{
   self.view.frame=CGRectMake(420, 0,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height);

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"Anim2" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    self.view.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
-(IBAction)nextView
{
    SecondViewController *sampleV=[[SecondViewController alloc] init];
    [self.view addSubview:sampleV.view];
    [self ViewNavigationOnLeftTabs];
}
```

Here I have added transition effect for the secondViewController exactly like your requirement. You need to handle the background view(view1) during the animation.

I have used this code in my app, and it's working fine for me.

Comment: Thanks for reply! I solved my problem by implementing a navigations controller, and shouldn't have posted this question. But since I have already posted it I will accept and upvote your answer, because it answers my original question, even though I'm not using your answer.

Comment: Apple discourages the use of these methods since iOS 4, you should use the block based methods instead.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using container view controllers. Here is a tutorial:
http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/04/containing-viewcontrollers/

Comment: This wasn't exactly what I'm looking for. I would prefer not to add any container view controllers, since I'm already done setting up the whole storyboard and all its view controllers. This mean I'm looking for codes to present view2 with the animation I explained in the question.